# Hyperledger framework block time benchmark

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, corda

Found references to block time on bitcoin (10 min) and Ethereum (10 to 15 sec), but haven't found any benchmark or reference to private blockchain performance. More specifically, any transaction performance benchmark data on Hyperledger Fabric and Corda?

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure: I work for R3, the company that are building the open source distributed ledger Corda.

Corda does not have a "global transaction speed limit" and this is because there is no centralisation of any part of the network. Also, we've designed Corda such that there is no requirement to include your transactions in the same blocks as other users - for the real world, it doesn't make sense to have to aggregate transactions in blocks like this.

Communication between nodes happens on a point to point basis; data that shouldn't be seen outside the parties involved in a transaction is never sent to those parties, they never see or are made aware that the transaction even exists. You can compare this to email - if users at @gmail.com are sending to users @yahoo.com, why should that effect the speed that @mail.ru can send to @hotmail.com ? Now obviously I have oversimplified this, but if I can point you to the Corda [non technical white paper](https://docs.corda.net/_static/corda-technical-whitepaper.pdf), you should be able to get a better understanding.

Effectively, you can transact with other members on the network as fast as you can send them network data ! Obviously, if you are dependent on other verifiers of these transactions, then this will slow you down, but otherwise no other actors or transactions on the network will affect your speed to transact.

Comment: I was hoping you'd tell us how much time before a new block is created on Hyperledger or Corda.